# Getting a map undefined error for search engine results page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I keep getting this error when it kicks over to my Suggestion method.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>   in Suggestions line 4

Can anyone help me figure out why, please?

I am a newb so forgive my ignorance.

```
import React from 'react';

const Suggestions = props => {
  const options = props.results.map (r => (
    <li key={r.id}>
      {r.name}
    </li>
  ));
  return <ul className="ul-list">{options}</ul>;
};

export default Suggestions;
```

Here is the rest of the code for the search bar. I removed api info but it was in there.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Suggestions from '../SearchBbg/suggestions';
import '../../style/searchbar.scss';

const API_KEY = '';
const API_URL = '';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: [],
  };

  getInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get (`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}&prefix=${this.state.query}&limit=7`)
      .then (({data}) => {
        this.setState ({
          results: data.data,
        });
      });
  };

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState (
      {
        query: this.search.value,
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            this.getInfo ();
          }
        } else if (!this.state.query) {
        }
      }
    );
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          className="search-bar"
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => (this.search = input)}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Suggestions results={this.state.results} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Whats the value of props.results? Are you even passing the results prop correctly? Paste the code where you are passing the result prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you already destructred in your **axios** call `data` property. That might be the reason why you got `undefined` for `props.results`.

So try the following:

```
getInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}&prefix=${this.state.query}&limit=7`)
      .then(({data}) => { // here already destructured
        this.setState ({
          results: data // removed => .data,
        });
      });
};
```

Additionally also worth to check for `null` or `undefined` value like `props.results && props.results.map()` before using `.map()`, so you can use like just to be sure:

```
const Suggestions = props => {
  const options = props.results && props.results.map (r => (
    <li key={r.id}>
      {r.name}
    </li>
  ));
  return <ul className="ul-list">{options}</ul>;
};
```

I hope this clarifies!

Comment: thank you, i tried that and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Your results array is undefined.
Check if you are passing **results** as a prop to Suggestions and if results array is not undefined.

Edit:

Seems that you are assigning some null or undefined to results, the only way this happens is on your api response. 
Check if you are parsing server response correctly.

Comment: I added it now, sorry.